# Dispatch function of pywin32 library does not work

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I use this function to access Excel and update the spreadsheet data, but now in the afternoon it doesn't want to work.
The function runs smoothly on my Windows 10, but on Windows Server 2012 it presents this problem.
Here's the code:

```
from win32com import client as win

def atualizar_planilha(file=''):
    try:
        excel = win.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        
        excel.Visible = False

        planilha = excel.Workbooks.open(file)

        planilha.RefreshAll()
        excel.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

        planilha.Save()
        planilha.Close(SaveChanges=True)
        excel.Quit()
        
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
```

all the previous code, the `Dispatch()` function is executed, but when it reaches it, it ends up resulting in this problem.
Someone to help me?

I already uninstalled and installed python and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: "resulting in this problem" -- What problem?  You never mentioned what really happened.  Do you actually have Excel installed on this system?  Server systems often don't have Office.

Comment: I have access to the server and excel is installed. The problem is that when you reach the dispacth() function, the program stops and is not finished. I'm using Google Translate to communicate, any questions regarding interpretation can ask

Comment: "resulting in this problem", meant "causing the problem"

Comment: Is the exception caught? if so, what is the message? My guess it is an account issue, and the application does not have rights to start Excel.

Comment: it doesn't show any exceptions, it just gets stuck on the line of code

Comment: Can you start Excel manually on the server successfully?

Comment: yes, i will try uninstall and install the excel